# How to use android apps in laptop without Bluestacks?

Tags: android, bluestacks

I like to use a testing app (NTA Abhyas) for JEE. It's a 3-hour test but I can't do it by looking on my phone for such a long time, so I decided to use it on PC using BlueStacks but for participating in the test we need to either switch off wifi or put it in airplane mode but I was unable to switch off wifi in android emulation of Bluestacks. Is it possible to off that or Is there any other software that satisfies my need? Please help me

Comment: Have you tried the Android emulator provided by Google which is part of the Android SDK?

Comment: @Robert Oh I don't about it. I will try that

Comment: You can use the Gemymotion emulator, connect your phone to window refer to this https://in.pcmag.com/gallery/126082/how-to-connect-windows-10-and-android-using-microsofts-your-phone-app or you can run android directly on a laptop with Android-X86

Comment: I don't suggest doing this—using testing apps in emulators is usually seen as suspicious. It's easy for the app to detect emulation like this and it might look like a cheating attempt.

Comment: @Joseph Oh. Till now I haven't used in emulator! but anyway I asked as I can't focus for 3 hours